# How to create Slack Incoming Webhook URL programmatically

Tags: slack-api, slack-commands

I have created a Slack app and in that I can create as many as incoming webhook URL's using the UI. I want to achieve the same through the code using their API if any.
Is there any reference or example where we can create incoming webhook URL's programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create incoming webhooks programmatically using the Slack API. They can only be created manually from your app's settings page.